# How To Change or refresh data using ViewBag in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to refresh the data in the view using ViewBag. Is it possible or may i use some other technique....

Here is my sample Code

**In My View Page** ( ***FamilyDetails***)

`@ViewBag.Details[0].Name`

**In My Controller**

```
public ActionResult FamilyDetails(string StrText)
    {
        if (StrText != null)
        {
            ViewBag.MarriageDetails = ListMarriages;
        }
        else
            ViewBag.MarriageDetails = ListMarriages1;
```

Please explain with code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is confusing. You assign some data to the MarriageDetails property then you're calling the Details property in the view. That makes no sense. And what do you mean by refreshing the data?

Comment: Hai MikeSW ,  Sorry its wrong assignment. Please assume by replacing Details with MarriageDetails to which list is assigned. I mean i want to change the  name which is displayed in my view,  with other name

Comment: I still don't understand what do you mean by refreshing. You assign the data and that's it.

Comment: ok.  At first please assume that the name in viewbag is gopal, and now when i reload the same view i want to update the name as venkatagopal.. thats it..

Answer (score 2):

You don't reload a view. The browser sends a request which is handled by a controller which then creates the view model (in this case the viewbag) then selects a view to which the view model is passed on.

You need to populate the view bag with the data you want in the controller. This is how an asp.net mvc application works.

If you want to update the view via ajax, then you just use jquery to invoke another action which will return the data you want as json or html, which it'll be inserted by the javascript. But in this case, the controller just returns a json result.

I think you really need to learn about asp.net mvc. The official site has basic tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials .