# modify viewbag content after page loaded

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to web dev and to MVC. In my view I have a video tag:

```
<video controls name="media" >
    <source src="~/Movies/@ViewBag.ViedoFileName" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And I have `<a>` tag like: `<a href="@Url.Action("Teeeest", "Video")">Click Here</a>`

I want that when clicking the `<a>` tag it will update the @ViewBag value, so inside `VideoController` I added (changed the ViewBag value and refreshed the page), but it doesn't updating the ViewBag and display the old ViewBag value:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Teeeest()
{
   @ViewBag.ViedoFileName = "vid2.mp4";//update value
   //refresh the page
   if (Session["type"] != null  && Session["resulttype"] != null)
        return View();
    else
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Change or refresh data using ViewBag in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600307/how-to-change-or-refresh-data-using-viewbag-in-mvc3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Teeeest()
{
   ViewBag.ViedoFileName = "vid2.mp4";
   return PartialView("Videos");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net MVC the only razor syntax started with `@` character. You don't need this to use in controllers. Just use this code

`ViewBag.ViedoFileName = "vid2.mp4";`

Hopefuly it will update your `ViewBag` value.